# How to set a property whose value is an enum

Tags: c#, oop, enums, bing-webmaster-tools

I'm new to C# and the .NET Framework. I'm building a small console app to "block" URLs from Bing's index because they were accidentally indexed. I'm using the [Bing Webmaster API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj572362.aspx) to do this.

I do not understand how to set two properties of the BlockedUrl object ([EntityType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj589688.aspx) and [RequestType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj589678.aspx)). The BlockedUrl object is passed to [AddBlockedUrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj589700.aspx) when sending the block request.

Setting the property values for [Url](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj589683.aspx), [Date](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj572359.aspx), and [DaysToExpire](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj589670.aspx) makes sense - they're given string, DateTime, and DaysToExpire values respectively as their signatures indicate.

Going by the signature of EntityType:

```
public BlockedUrl.BlockedUrlEntityType EntityType { get; set; }
```

I don't understand BlockedUrl.BlockedUrlEntityType or how I would work with it. The RequestType property is similar.

My current code is below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string url = "https://url/dir/path/";
            var api = new WebmasterApi.WebmasterApiClient();
            var blockedURLObj = new WebmasterApi.BlockedUrl();
            blockedURLObj.Url = url;
            blockedURLObj.Date = new DateTime(2018, 5, 8, 8, 00, 00);
            blockedURLObj.DaysToExpire = 90;
            blockedURLObj.EntityType = "Directory"; //error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to ConsoleApp1.WebmasterApi.BlockedUrl.BlockedUrlEntityType"
            blockedURLObj.RequestType = "FullRemoval"; //error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to ConsoleApp1.WebmasterApi.BlockedUrl.BlockedUrlRequestType"

        try
        {
            api.AddBlockedUrl(url, blockedURLObj);
            Console.WriteLine("Success!");
            Console.ReadLine(); 
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EntityType property should be set using an enumeration value as dictated here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh969362.aspx

The RequestType proeprty should be set using an enumeration value as dictated here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh969383.aspx

For example:

```
blockedURLObj.EntityType = BlockedUrl.BlockedUrlEntityType.Directory;
blockedURLObj.RequestType = BlockedUrl.BlockedUrlRequestType.FullRemoval;
```

Answer (score 1):

`BlockedUrl.BlockedUrlEntityType` is a enum

So you need something like

```
blockedURLObj.EntityType = BlockedUrl.BlockedUrlEntityType.Directory;
blockedURLObj.RequestType = BlockedUrl.BlockedUrlRequestType.FullRemoval;
```

More about enums here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum

Answer (score 1):

So the `EntityType` and `RequestType` look like enums. you can set it via `blockedURLObj.RequestType = WebmasterApi.BlockedUrl.BlockedUrlRequestType.FullRemoval;` and `blockedURLObj.EntityType = WebmasterApi.BlockedUrl.BlockedUrlEntityType.Directory;`